# Can not set java.lang.String field CustomersEntity.address to CustomersEntity,Is something wrong with the address field in CustomerEntity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to save a new instance of CustomersEntity to my database via hibernate. After debugging the exact line that causes my error is: "session.save(newCustomer)" I have printed the contents of this "newCustomer" and all fields are present except the ID field. I am pretty sure that I have annotated my Id field correctly for hibernate, but I may be wrong. I have been stuck on this so any insight will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Indexed;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "customers", schema = "customer_db", catalog = "")
    public class CustomersEntity {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private Timestamp lastEmailSent;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int customerId;



@Basic
@Column(name = "lastName")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "firstName")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "address")
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "city")
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "state")
public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "zip")
public String getZip() {
    return zip;
}

public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "lastEmailSent")
public Timestamp getLastEmailSent() {
    return lastEmailSent;
}

public void setLastEmailSent(Timestamp lastEmailSent) {
    this.lastEmailSent = lastEmailSent;
}


@Column(name = "customerId")
public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}
public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    CustomersEntity that = (CustomersEntity) o;
    return customerId == that.customerId &&
            Objects.equals(lastName, that.lastName) &&
            Objects.equals(firstName, that.firstName) &&
            Objects.equals(email, that.email) &&
            Objects.equals(address, that.address) &&
            Objects.equals(city, that.city) &&
            Objects.equals(state, that.state) &&
            Objects.equals(zip, that.zip) &&
            Objects.equals(lastEmailSent, that.lastEmailSent);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(lastName, firstName, email, address, city, state, 
    zip, lastEmailSent, customerId);
}
```

}

I am getting the error "Can not set java.lang.String field ...model.CustomersEntity.address to ...model.CustomersEntity. Any insight as to  what is the issue? I am sorry if my question has triggered anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in your code where you are attempting to save this entity you are setting the address with the entity itself instead of an address string.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check your controller logic where you are creating your customer object. Also make sure property declarations in your hibernate mapping files are correct.